# Razor Pages return an Image in handler to an ``<img>`` element

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

In MVC, we can return an image at controller using:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoadImageFile(string name)
{
    byte[] Buf = System.IO.ReadAllBytes(name);
    return File(Buf, "image/png");
}
```

And then in my cshtml

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/myController/LoadImageFile")?name=test.jpg" />
```

May I know how can I do that in Razor Pages handler? I am trying something like this below and it doesn't work:

```
public IActionResult OnGetLoadImageFile(string name)
{
    byte[] Buf = System.IO.ReadAllBytes(name);
    return File(Buf, "image/png", name);
}

<img src="@Url.Page("~/myPage", "LoadImageFile")?name=test.png" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LoadImageFile` handler is in `Pages/Index.cshtml.cs`,your url should be like below:

```
<img src="@Url.Page("Index","LoadImageFile",new {name="test.jpg" })" />
```

Or:

```
<img src="@Url.Page("/Index","LoadImageFile",new {name="test.jpg" })" />
```

If `LoadImageFile` handler is in `Pages/FolderName/Index.cshtml.cs`,your url should be like below:

```
<img src="@Url.Page("FolderName/Index","LoadImageFile",new {name="test.jpg" })" />
```

Or:

```
<img src="@Url.Page("/FolderName/Index","LoadImageFile",new {name="test.jpg" })" />
```